# top alignment of TOC entries spanning two pages

Tags: pdftex

I have a TOC (table of content) spanning two pages. I'd like the ENTRIES of the pages to be top-aligned. See image.

[image]

documentclass: `scrbook`
compile: `pdflatex`

Note that I redefined the style of my Chapter titles as:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\newcommand{\fncchap}{
    \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-30pt}{27pt}  % fancy title format style
    \titleformat{\chapter}[display]
        {\normalfont\sffamily\Huge\bfseries}
        {\Large{\chaptertitlename~\thechapter}\filleft}{1pt}
        {\titlerule\vspace{40pt}}
        [\vspace{15pt}]
    }
```

Obviously, this question applies to TOC, TOF, TOT, and chapter beginnings. Thanks for any suggestions!